# how to implement Python socket.unwrap() in c?

Tags: python, c, sockets

I have refered to the following webpage :

https://serverfault.com/questions/153983/sockets-found-by-lsof-but-not-by-netstat

Using Python, I have encountered the same problem on SSL sockets:
    When I use `socket.close()`, the socket stays in CLOSE_WAIT state for an indefinite time
    when I use `socket.shutdown()`, lsof says "can't identify protocol"

The solution was to unwrap the SSL layer before closing:

```
origsock = socket.unwrap()
origsock.close()
```

This closes the sockets properly in my app.

I like to ask what `unwrap()` does in python and how to do it in c ?!

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.unwrap)?

Comment: How are you doing the SSL communication in C? It should have a method to perform the SSL shutdown, which you should do before closing the socket. That's what `unwrap()` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unwrap` does a proper SSL shutdown. Such shutdown is similar to the FIN handshake at the end of the TCP connection, only at the SSL/TLS layer. How this shutdown is done in  C depends on the specific SSL/TLS stack you are using. But for OpenSSL the function you need to use is [SSL_shutdown](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:SSL_shutdown(3)).